# GTA V won't start up

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

GTA V won't load at all. It won't give an error message, won't tell me why either. I've gotten the game to load one (1) time. I haven't been able to get it to run at all.

I've messaged Rockstar about this and they emailed me back some basic troubleshooting techniques:

1. Restart the game
2. Update your Video Card (RTX 2070)
3. Uninstall and reinstall

None of those worked. I've talked with them extensively in email for a month before and they didn't know what to do. I'm on a Windows 10 machine. Custom built.

Down below are all my specs. You can see my tweet to Rockstar on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Tarrabyte/status/1233885915728269312).

```
OS
    Windows 10 Home 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Core i7 @ 3.70GHz 39 °C
    Coffee Lake 14nm Technology
RAM
    32.0GB Single-Channel Unknown @ 1069MHz (15-15-15-36)
Motherboard
    ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG STRIX Z390-E GAMING (LGA1151) 39 °C
Graphics
    S22C350 (1920x1080@59Hz)
    VG248 (1920x1080@60Hz)
    Intel UHD Graphics 630 (ASUStek Computer Inc)
    4095MB NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 (EVGA)   55 °C
    ForceWare version: 442.19
    SLI Disabled
Storage
    3726GB Western Digital WDC WD4005FZBX-00K5WB0 (SATA )   38 °C
    232GB Samsung SSD 970 EVO 250GB (Unknown (SSD))
    3725GB Western Digital WD My Book 1235 USB Device (USB (SATA) ) 38 °C
Optical Drives
    No optical disk drives detected
Audio
    High Definition Audio Device
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I see you uninstalled the game and reinstalled - but did you try installing it on a different drive?  If that doesn't work, maybe try the nuclear option and reinstall Windows.

Comment: If every other game works, wouldn't that be pointless? GTA V is the only game that doesn't work; The only drive I have other than my main install drive is my SSD which has the Sims (1&4) and windows on it basically. (other small programs I want the best performance but that's another story.) I'm trying to keep that from being used. A 4TB for extra media. But that won't be useful in this situation 

So I don't know what's going. I mean, I was thinking of getting a 2nd drive anyways so this could be a test I suppose. But I have a feeling it's not going to do me any good.

Comment: Try moving the `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V` folder elsewhere or rename it to something else. There are settings stored there that might be screwing things up. Just don't delete it as your save files are also in there.

Comment: I've not even had the chance to play the game to save anything, but I can try that I guess.

Comment: Can you follow the steps provided [here](https://superuser.com/a/603488/663024) and see if anything comes up in the log?

Comment: Also try to check `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Rockstar Games\Launcher\launcher.log`. It should tell you why it crashed when RGL tried to start it.

Comment: There is also `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\launcher.log` with the detailed crash information (I have used it in the past).

Comment: @Lemon found it and it said the reason for the crash is error code "0xc0000005" but when I checked it online and found something from 2015 people said to delete a few files and that seemed to work, gonna test it. Then if it doesn't work, I'm seriously going to get ahold of Rockstar somehow.

Comment: HOLY SHIT 
https://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/611703999981246876/
That's what fixed it all!

Comment: So new issue, it's doing the same thing again and this time I don't have any of those files. I don't even have a log file.

Comment: 0xc0000005 is an Access Violation error. This means that the game tried to write into invalid memory locations or the game memory (RAM) is corrupted. There is nothing that you can do to fix this. I would recommend trying to contact Rockstar Support to see what they can do.

Comment: I've been trying to and they are completely useless. @Lemon

Comment: In that case, there is nothing else that you can try. A SIGSEGV is an error that happens with GTA V and there is no way to fix it yourself. I have created mods for the game, so I have a bit of experience with SIGSEGV, Access Violations or 0xc0000005 in GTA V.

Comment: @Lemon well hell, Guess I'll have to figure something out. I don't get why this is happening. So you have never found any way around this?